# Rails: Why does where(id: objects) work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following statement:

```
Customer.where(city_id: cities)
```

which results in the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT customers.* FROM customers WHERE customers.city_id IN (SELECT cities.id FROM cities...
```

Is this intended behavior? Is it documented somewhere? I will not use the Rails code above and use one of the followings instead:

```
Customer.where(city_id: cities.pluck(:id))
```

or

```
Customer.where(city: cities)
```

which results in the exact same SQL statement.

Answer (score 7):

The AREL querying library allows you to pass in ActiveRecord objects as a short-cut. It'll then pass their primary key attributes into the SQL it uses to contact the database.

When looking for multiple objects, the AREL library will attempt to find the information in as few database round-trips as possible. It does this by holding the query you're making as a set of conditions, until it's time to retrieve the objects.

This way would be inefficient:

```
users = User.where(age: 30).all
#                           ^^^ get all these users from the database
memberships = Membership.where(user_id: users)
#                                       ^^^^^ This will pass in each of the ids as a condition
```

Basically, this way would issue two SQL statements:

```
select * from users where age = 30;
select * from memberships where user_id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Each of these involves a call on a network port between applications and the data to then be passsed back across that same port.

---

This would be more efficient:

```
users = User.where(age: 30)
# This is still a query object, it hasn't asked the database for the users yet.
memberships = Membership.where(user_id: users)
# Note: this line is the same, but users is an AREL query, not an array of users
```

It will instead build a single, nested query so it only has to make a round-trip to the database once.

```
select * from memberships 
where user_id in (
  select id from users where age = 30
);
```

So, yes, it's expected behaviour. It's a bit of Rails magic, it's designed to improve your application's performance without you having to know about how it works.

---

There's also some cool optimisations, like if you call `first` or `last` instead of `all`, it will only retrieve one record.

```
User.where(name: 'bob').all
# SELECT "USERS".* FROM "USERS" WHERE "USERS"."NAME" = 'bob'
User.where(name: 'bob').first
# SELECT "USERS".* FROM "USERS" WHERE "USERS"."NAME" = 'bob' AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

Or if you set an order, and call last, it will reverse the order then only grab the last one in the list (instead of grabbing all the records and only giving you the last one).

```
User.where(name: 'bob').order(:login).first
# SELECT * FROM (SELECT "USERS".* FROM "USERS" WHERE "USERS"."NAME" = 'bob' ORDER BY login) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
User.where(name: 'bob').order(:login).first
# SELECT * FROM (SELECT "USERS".* FROM "USERS" WHERE "USERS"."NAME" = 'bob' ORDER BY login DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
# Notice, login DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

> Why does it work?

Something deep in the ActiveRecord query builder is smart enough to see that if you pass an array or a query/criteria, it needs to build an `IN` clause.

> Is this documented anywhere?

Yes, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions

#### 2.3.3 Subset conditions

> If you want to find records using the IN expression you can pass an array to the conditions hash:
>
> ```
> Client.where(orders_count: [1,3,5])
> ```
>
> This code will generate SQL like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.orders_count IN (1,3,5))
> ```

Comment: Using an array of integer makes sense to convert to a IN statement, but why does this also work with objects? What if cities primary key is not id but something else?

Comment: @0lli.rocks: in most cases, when you pass an AR object into the query builder, it's reduced to its id (primary key). Like `Project.find(user: u)` will result in `select * from projects where user_id = 123`. ActiveRecord has a lot of helpful magic like this.